# Inconsistent overload resolution with rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11

My understanding of overload resolution is that 'T&&' is generally a better match than 'const T&'. However, I'm seeing some inconsistent behavior among compilers with this trivial example:

```
#include <iostream>

void Func(const double& a)
{
    (void)a;
    std::cout << "[lvalue]\n";
}

void Func(double&& a)
{
    (void)a;
    std::cout << "[rvalue]\n";
}

template <typename T>
void TFunc(T&& a)
{
    Func(a);
}

int main ()
{
    TFunc(5.5f);

    return 0;
}
```

Clang 3.2 will print **[rvalue]**. However, the VS2013 32bit/64bit compilers will print **[lvalue]**. If I change '5.5f' to '5.5', then both compilers will print **[lvalue]**.

I can understand why the VS compiler chooses the 'const double&' version since I don't have a std::forward call to preserve the '&&' of the parameter. However, I still don't understand what makes clang think that the '&&' overload is the better choice.

Why does adding an implicit float to double conversion affect the behavior in clang? Who is right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call with `5.5f`, `T` is float, and the `Func` call effectively becomes `Func(double(a))`. The argument is a temporary, and so rvalue overload should be chosen.

When you call with `5.5`, `T` is double, and no temporary is created in a call to `Func(a)`. A named variable cannot bind to an rvalue reference, so lvalue overload is the only choice.

MSVC has a long-standing misfeature that allows temporaries to bind to non-const lvalue references. This is why it incorrectly chooses lvalue overload even in the first case. Try compiling with `/Za` (disable language extensions) - I believe it would match clang's behavior then.

Comment: Why isn't a temporary created when `T = double`?

Comment: `5.5` within `TFunc` is `a`, which has a name and thus is an l-value.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm currently not in front of a machine with VS2013, but /Za doesn't fix the problem in VS2012.

Comment: For anyone else who found this SO Q&A trying to figure why their rvalue reference overload isn't being called, in a different case, and dealing with `std::string`s father than doubles, I was able to "force" a call to the rvalue version by changing the call `Func(a);` to `Func(std::move(a));`.  Your actual mileage may vary, of course.